# Python - How do I find a file in a folder if I don't know the extension?

Tags: python, macos

Suppose I have the full path of a file **except** the extension:

```
FileNoExt = "/Users/username/Desktop/song"
```

I need to retrieve the full path **including** the file extension and pass that into a variable:

```
FileWithExt = "/Users/username/Desktop/song.mp3"
```

I've found a lot of similar questions on stackexchange; however, none of the answers seem to work. I'm using PyCharm on macOS.

Comment: if that is the case, u shouldn't be hardcoding this value. Instead, you should execute a shell command (subprocess in this case) to find the file. Then store the result in your var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the answer from [Han Solo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59484396/5431791) seems better, here's an alternative way. You can iterate the folder contents and check if the filename matches the start of any file:

```
import os

FileNoExt = "/Users/username/Desktop/song"
directory, prefix = FileNoExt.rsplit('/',1)
for f in os.listdir(directory):
    if f.starswith(prefix):
        FileWithExt = os.path.join(directory,f)
        break
```

**Note:**

This will only contain files that start with the prefix, but may have other characters before the extension, and break as soon as one match is found. If you want all the files with the prefix, you can append each of the matching cases in a list. You can also check for specific extenstions with `endswith`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `glob` module like,

```
>>> import glob
>>> file_wo_ext = '/home/xxx/python/doc'
>>> glob.glob(file_wo_ext + '*')
['/home/xxx/python/doc.comments', '/home/xxx/python/doc.fornow']
```

or if you are used to `pathlib` then, you can do something like,

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> file_wo_ext = '/home/xxx/python/doc'
>>> p = pathlib.Path(file_wo_ext)
>>> p.parent
PosixPath('/home/xxx/python')
>>> p.stem
'doc'
>>> list(p.parent.glob(p.stem + '*'))
[PosixPath('/home/xxx/python/doc.comments'), PosixPath('/home/xxx/python/doc.fornow')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a longer but more understandable solution showing some of what happens "behind the scenes"; it retrieves the absoltue path (with extension) of  *first match* of `filename`:

```py
import os

def get_fullpath(path_wo_ext):
    target_name = path_wo_ext.split(os.sep)[-1]         # os.sep == "/" for your OS
    folderpath  = path_wo_ext.replace(target_name, '')  # exclude name to get folderpath
    filenames   = sorted(os.listdir(folderpath))        # get all filenames w/ extensions,
                                                        # and sort for consistency
    return [os.path.join(folderpath, name) for name filenames
                                           if name in filename][0]

fullpath = get_fullpath("/Users/username/Desktop/song")
```

To return all matches, remove the `[0]`